# javascript - DataTables - updating row using fnUpdate replaces different row

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, row, edit

I have **Edit** buttons in each row, on *click* data from row is passed to modal, where a user can change it, then on **Save** in modal it should update that row.

I am using ***fnUpdate***, however instead of updating (replacing) intended row, different row is replaced...

```
var uId                 = $(this).closest('.modal-content').find('input[name=uId]').val();
var fNameUpdated        = $(this).closest('.modal-content').find('input[name=fName]').val();
var lNameUpdated        = $(this).closest('.modal-content').find('input[name=lName]').val();
var uTypeUpdated        = $(this).closest('.modal-content').find('.dropdown-toggle').attr('title');
var uNameUpdated        = $(this).closest('.modal-content').find('input[name=uName]').val();
var uPasswordUpdated    = $(this).closest('.modal-content').find('input[name=password]').val();
var buttons             = 'buttons';

// updating row using fnUpdate from datatable
var oTable = $('#dataTables-example').dataTable();
oTable.fnUpdate( [uId, fNameUpdated, lNameUpdated, uTypeUpdated, uNameUpdated, uPasswordUpdated, buttons], trIndex );
```

***trIndex*** is received earlier:

```
var trIndex;
$('#dataTables-example').dataTable().find('tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
   trIndex = this.rowIndex;
});
```

Table before editing row 1:

```
+-----+------------+-----------+---------+----------+------+---------------+
| ID  | First Name | Last Name |  Type   | Username | Pass |    Action     |
+-----+------------+-----------+---------+----------+------+---------------+
| 1   | Mark       | Knopfler  | admin   | Mark     | pass | Edit / Delete |
| 2   | Peter      | Pan       | admin   | Peter    | pass | Edit / Delete |
| 3   | Bob        | Dylan     | regUser | Bob      | pass | Edit / Delete |
| 4   | Harry      | Angel     | regUser | Harry    | pass | Edit / Delete |
| ... | ...        | ...       | ...     | ...      | ...  | ...           |
+-----+------------+-----------+---------+----------+------+---------------+
```

Table after editing row 1:

```
+-----+------------+-----------+---------+----------+------+---------------+
| ID  | First Name | Last Name |  Type   | Username | Pass |    Action     |
+-----+------------+-----------+---------+----------+------+---------------+
| 1   | Mark       | Knopfler  | admin   | Mark     | pass | Edit / Delete |
| 1   | Harrison   | Ford      | regUser | Harrison | pass | Edit / Delete |
| 3   | Bob        | Dylan     | regUser | Bob      | pass | Edit / Delete |
| 4   | Harry      | Angel     | regUser | Harry    | pass | Edit / Delete |
| ... | ...        | ...       | ...     | ...      | ...  | ...           |
+-----+------------+-----------+---------+----------+------+---------------+
```

Could anyone advise please.

Edit:

1) probably there is a more efficient way of collecting data

2) field *Pass* is for testing purposes only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution found:

Apparently method for receiving ***trIndex*** was wrong and should be corrected with the following:

```
$('#dataTables-example tbody').on('click', 'td', function () {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    rowIndex = tr.index();
});
```

Above seems to be working fine.